# android list add is not adding hashmap

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I am using using listview for adding list in my android app. when i am using for loop in hashmap it showing the list but all the datas are in final list for example the below code is working as fine.

```
products = new ArrayList<Cash>(products);   
HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

temp.put("item1", "id1";
temp.put("item2", "name1");
temp.put("item3", "qty1");
temp.put("item4", "type1");
temp.put("item5", "quantity1");
temp.put("item6", "amt1");

list.add(temp);

temp1.put("item1", "id2";
temp1.put("item2", "name2");
temp1.put("item3", "qty2");
temp1.put("item4", "type2");
temp1.put("item5", "quantity2");
temp1.put("item6", "amt2");

list.add(temp1);
ListViewAdapters adapter1=new ListViewAdapters(getActivity(), list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

It's working as fine but when i want to add multiple items using for loop. The code is shown below. The products is the array list having the items.

```
    products = new ArrayList<Cash>(products);
    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
    list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

     for (int i=0; i<products.size();i++){
            Log.d("LOG","Product size:"+products.size());
            Log.d("LOG","Product name:"+products.get(i).getName());
            Log.d("LOG","Product amt:"+products.get(i).getAmount());
            temp.put("item1", String.valueOf(i));
            temp.put("item2", products.get(i).getName());
            temp.put("item3", products.get(i).getQuantity());
            temp.put("item4", products.get(i).getType());
            temp.put("item5", products.get(i).getQuantity());
            temp.put("item6", products.get(i).getAmount());

            list.add(i, temp);
            //list.

        }

    ListViewAdapters adapter1=new ListViewAdapters(getActivity(), list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

The output i want

id1 name1 qty1 type1 quantity1 amt1
id2 name2 qty2 type2 quantity2 amt2

But getting output is

id2 name2 qty2 type2 quantity2 amt2
id2 name2 qty2 type2 quantity2 amt2

Comment: It is updating not creating new. use `HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();` inside loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are updating `HashMap` in every iteration, instead create new instance as in

```
 for (int i=0; i<products.size();i++){
            Log.d("LOG","Product size:"+products.size());
            Log.d("LOG","Product name:"+products.get(i).getName());
            Log.d("LOG","Product amt:"+products.get(i).getAmount());

            temp = new HashMap<String,String>(); //<-- add this line

            temp.put("item1", String.valueOf(i));
            temp.put("item2", products.get(i).getName());
            temp.put("item3", products.get(i).getQuantity());
            temp.put("item4", products.get(i).getType());
            temp.put("item5", products.get(i).getQuantity());
            temp.put("item6", products.get(i).getAmount());

            list.add(i, temp);
            //list.

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `HashMap` before you adding new values.Check below:

**temp=new HashMap();**

```
for (int i=0; i<products.size();i++){
    temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Log.d("LOG","Product size:"+products.size());
    Log.d("LOG","Product name:"+products.get(i).getName());
    Log.d("LOG","Product amt:"+products.get(i).getAmount());
    temp.put("item1", String.valueOf(i));
    temp.put("item2", products.get(i).getName());
    temp.put("item3", products.get(i).getQuantity());
    temp.put("item4", products.get(i).getType());
    temp.put("item5", products.get(i).getQuantity());
    temp.put("item6", products.get(i).getAmount());

    list.add(i, temp);
}
```